# Path for button without id or name in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<span class=“MuiButton-label">
<span class="MuiButton-startIcon MuiButton-iconSizeMedium”>
<span class=“MuiButton-label"> <span class="MuiButton-startIcon MuiButton-iconSizeMedium”> <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 enter code here0 24 24" data-testid=“SaveIcon"> <path d="somevalue”> Create
```

How do I create an path for above code?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Create')]")).click();
```

I tried like this but didn't work and not giving any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it being more specific in the `By.xpath()`:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'MuiButton-label') and contains(text(),'Create')]")).click();
```